# How do I add a line in the beginning of a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++, what is the proper way to insert a line at the beginning of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179349/in-c-what-is-the-proper-way-to-insert-a-line-at-the-beginning-of-a-text-file)

How do I add a line in the beginning of a file in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Use fseek function to move the cursor to the file start and add the contents in the beginning of the file.

Refer this link [FSEEK](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/)

Comment: That will overwrite the existing data at the beginning of the file.