# Adding Data at beginning of file

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete a Line from a file in C Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151713/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-language)
>   [In C++, what is the proper way to insert a line at the beginning of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179349/in-c-what-is-the-proper-way-to-insert-a-line-at-the-beginning-of-a-text-file)

How can i add data at the beginning of a file using c/c++ programming?
I have tried following code :

```
fstream file;  

stmt.open(L"d:\\xyz.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
```

but this is appending at the end of file.

Comment: Please post complete code, not just random lines (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: It may be better and more advantageous to design your program so that this is not required, or that you have space already allocated at the start of the file.

Comment: The `ios::app` attribute forces all writes to end of file.  If you want to write to the beginning, they you shouldn't use it.  (But as others have pointed out, you can only overwrite existing data or append to the end.  You cannot insert data into a file.)

Answer (score 9):

You cannot do that.

With only standard C or C++, if you want to do it atomically, you have to write everything to a new file (i.e. new data plus old file), and then move the file over. If you want to play it risky, you can read a block of data, and write the new content at the beginning and move the data up block by block (but if something interrupts you, you've destroyed the file).

If you have access to memory mapping, you can try a different approach: Memory-map the entire file, `memmove` it by the required offset, and `memcpy` the new data into the initial segment.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

- Create a new file
- Add the new data at the top
- Append the data from the old file

There's `rename` in `cstdio` but I'm sure there's also something C++-specific.

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Your only options of opening a file as far as i know are read,write and append. Therefore you should read the entire file content (provided it's not a huge file), open a temp file for writing , then write what you want followed by the buffer you read from the old file.

You can also try to open the file in w+ mode and try to position the cursor at the beginning of the file but i don't know if that would work unfortunately